# Copy-Item shortcut fails to copy

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a list of files I need to put on every new computer my company gets and I have automated it all with PowerShell, but I can't get this last part to work.
This is the command that is not working I'm wanting to put a shortcut in the start_Menu. What I have found out is that in order for myself to put a file in the location it requests administrator permission to copy. My account is an Admin so I just click continue and file will transfer. I want it automated.

```
Copy-Item G:\Work\BGInfo\updatebginfo.lnk C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start_Menu -Force
```

Also when I test the file location it comes back false even if I have manually put the shortcut at the location.

```
Test-Path C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start_Menu\updatebginfo.lnk
```

Comment: Do you have a domain environment? Group Policy Preferences provide simpler handling and better control.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yes and no but it will be easier Beacuse not all of are computers are on the Domain. I have been able to set it up where the all the files move in sept the shortcut file.

Comment: If for some you can't (or don't want to) do it with GPP, you should be able to get around the problem by running your code/script from an elevated PowerShell.

Comment: Even with elevated powershell it still wont move the shortcut or verify if the file is there. @AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after looking into more of the Developer code from Microsoft I found the answer. According to what I found was to add "" when any code in PowerShell needs to have a space.

Original code:
Copy-Item G:\Work\BGInfo\updatebginfo.lnk C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start_Menu -Force

Correct code:
Copy-Item "G:\Work\BGInfo\updatebginfo.lnk C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu" -Force